# Reading into collection and retrieving top 5

Tags: collections

I was asked this recently in an interview. Application that is reading ticker and trade volume from a live feed, 
E.g. AAPL 1000, TWTR 500, MSFT 500, AAPL 500 ... 
So, AAPL total volume = 1500 and so on.
I have to read these into a collection and return the top 5 by volume.

I had suggested to use a hash map when storing and then sort or use a Treemap.
Any other way that is more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ticker symbol and trade volume are stored together in an instance of some class TickerAndTradeVolume, you could have references to objects contained in multiple data structures.

So a hash map may have ticker symbol as key and TickerAndTradeVolume as value. Then references to TickerAndTradeVolume instances can also be stored in a priority queue. Instances are re-inserted into the PQ on every volume update.

The top n by volume are always available in log(n) amortized time complexity to maintain priorities by trade volume, which is asymptotically faster than sorting via Treemap time and again.

Something like this

```
    Map<String, TickerAndTradeVolume> feed;
    PriorityQueue<TickerAndTradeVolume> pq;

    class TickerAndTradeVolume implements Comparable<TickerAndTradeVolume> {
        private String ticker;
        private double volume;

        TickerAndTradeVolume(String ticker, double volume) {
            this.ticker = ticker;
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        void increaseVolumeBy(double volume) {
            this.volume += volume;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(TickerAndTradeVolume that) {
            return (int) (that.volume - this.volume);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if(obj instanceof String) {
                TickerAndTradeVolume that = (TickerAndTradeVolume) obj;
                return this.ticker.equals(that.ticker);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    void addOrUpdateStockVolume(TickerAndTradeVolume tt) {
        if(!feed.containsKey(tt.ticker)) {
            feed.put(tt.ticker, tt);
            pq.add(tt);
        }
        else {
            feed.get(tt.ticker).increaseVolumeBy(tt.volume);
            // take out and put back in to trigger heap operations
            pq.remove(feed.get(tt.ticker));
            pq.add(feed.get(tt.ticker));
        }
    }

    List<TickerAndTradeVolume> getTopMaxFive() {
        List<TickerAndTradeVolume> topFive = new ArrayList<TickerAndTradeVolume>(5);
        int pqSize = pq.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5 && i < pqSize; i++) {
            // poll() takes from the top of the heap
            topFive.add(pq.poll());
        }
        for(TickerAndTradeVolume tt : topFive) {
            // put back what we took out
            pq.add(tt);
        }
        return topFive;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement this. So, to start I will have a hashmap<String,Double> to store the ticker and volume. How do I make these as references to be stored in a priority queue? A brief pseudo code would help.

Comment: The type stored in a priority queue has to be comparable. In this case, just storing volume as a double isn't sufficient. The ticker info has to be stored as well. We can use a class to encapsulate the notion of a ticker and its trading volume.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add some sample code. Obviously the difference in performance is increasingly more pronounced as the number of stored tickers grows. This also has to do with having to sort all n entries vs. always just pulling the top five from the heap.